# elementary OS on HP Probook 450 G4

Tags: hp

I have an HP Probook 450 G4 and I was thinking about changing from Windows to Linux. I started to read about the different distros and I totally fell in love with elementary OS.

Unfortunately, I couldn't really find much specific information about my laptop model (except it is not on the list of verified laptops for Ubuntu). So I wanted help from people with more know-how about the topic to tell me if it could be a good fit for my laptop or to get recommendations about better alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elementary OS (as most other Linux distros nowadays) comes with a Live Image. That means you can "burn" the ISO image to an USB Stick (hint: use the programm "Etcher" for that), plug that stick into your laptop and boot off from said USB stick.

No modifications are made to your existing OS. You can try out nearly all the features like WiFi support, keyboard hotkeys, sound, ...

Once you are certain that everything that is supposed to work actually does work you can fire up the installer and make the OS your permanent choice. During the installation you can even select between wiping the entire harddrive (and thus effectivly removing Windows) OR you can resize the existing partition and install Elementary OS alongside Windows.

Comment: That's a great thing to know! I'll try the Live Image and see how it works.
Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. Could you please accept/upvote my answer? Thanks! :)